# Convention for multiline generics declarations

Tags: java, generics

I often find myself with ridiculously long method signatures when using generics.

Something like this:

```
CompletionStage<StatusReply<MyAwesomeEntity.MyAwesomeResponse>> doStuff()
```

I like to keep 80 chars limit in my source code. The above return type takes >60 chars, there's not much space left for method name and arguments (that can also have some generics).

Are there any style guidelines/conventions out there to help break such long lines involving generics and mantain code readibility?

Before this questions gets shut down as "opinion based". I am not asking about how would you break it, I am asking about style guidelines document coming form the likes of Oracle that I can refer to.

Comment: How the compiler could be able to determine the return type of the method if you don't specify it in the signature?
Of course you could break it but it may not what you want to do.

Comment: What about introducing `class MyCompletionStage extends CompletionStage<StatusReply<MyAwesomeEntity.MyAwesomeResponse>> {}`?

Answer (score -1):

> „*…conventions out there to help break such long lines involving generics and mantain code readibility?…*“

Yes. You can learn about the *`var`* convention in [*JEP 238: Local Variable Type Inference*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

> „*…I am asking about style guidelines document coming form the likes of Oracle that I can refer to…*“

You can refer to [*OpenJDK's style guidelines for using var*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) and [*the Local Variable Type Inference: FAQ*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIFAQ.html).

Comment: You can't use `var` in method signatures.

Comment: Oh! That's a method signature? It was too long. So I didn't read it very carefully. HehHeh! It looked like an assignment to me. But if the downvote made you feel better, I'll leave it here for you to savor for a short while.